# Got a EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY symbol crash, Not able to track what when wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, ios9

I tried to genarate a build on xCode 12 and installed on iPad 2 with iOS 9. I have support for iOS 9 enabled but app automatically closes on opening. When doing track trace. I found following report which i am not able to understand because i am newbie in iOS development and the app i am creating using React native:

```
    Incident Identifier: D9CAEF74-EB00-427D-87CE-59AD04B867AD
    CrashReporter Key:   a9d16763e1e95beac1c4f2df37e45ebd8b0c5147
    Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
    Process:             {App name} [208]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE909A08-5A38-407B-A176-CBD73EE1D269/{App name}.app/{App name}
    Identifier:          {App bundle}
    Version:             3 (1.0)
    Code Type:           ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]
    
    Date/Time:           2020-10-22 16:10:39.39 +0530
    Launch Time:         2020-10-22 16:10:36.36 +0530
    OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
    Report Version:      104
    
    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Triggered by Thread:  4
    
    Filtered syslog:
    None found
    
    Last Exception Backtrace:
    (0x21f17916 0x216b2e12 0x8b692 0x10667c 0x107392 0x21f1c4c0 0x21e42878 0x21e462f2 0xbc968 0xbea8c 0xbe6f6 0x21a8581e 0x21a9241e 0x21a91a5c 0x21a945e4 0x21a93fc8 0x21c49b24 0x21c49714)
    
    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21b8e8d0 0x21b8e000 + 2256
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21b8e6d4 0x21b8e000 + 1748
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x21ed9ac4 0x21e1e000 + 768708
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x21ed7e4c 0x21e1e000 + 761420
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x21e27228 0x21e1e000 + 37416
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x21e27014 0x21e1e000 + 36884
    6   GraphicsServices                0x23417ac8 0x2340e000 + 39624
    7   UIKit                           0x264fb188 0x2647f000 + 508296
    8   Medixcel Doctor                 0x00029008 0x22000 + 28680
    9   libdyld.dylib                   0x21acf872 0x21acd000 + 10354
    
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21ba3864 0x21b8e000 + 88164
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c49b34 0x21c48000 + 6964
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c49718 0x21c48000 + 5912
    
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21ba3864 0x21b8e000 + 88164
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c49b34 0x21c48000 + 6964
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c49718 0x21c48000 + 5912
    
    Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21ba42f8 0x21b8e000 + 90872
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x21a99d60 0x21a83000 + 93536
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x21a99abe 0x21a83000 + 92862
    
    Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
    Thread 4 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21ba2c5c 0x21b8e000 + 85084
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c4c732 0x21c48000 + 18226
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x21b370ac 0x21aec000 + 307372
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x2168eae4 0x2168e000 + 2788
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x216a769e 0x2168e000 + 104094
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x216b30b0 0x216ac000 + 28848
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x216a4e16 0x2168e000 + 93718
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x216a45f4 0x2168e000 + 91636
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x216b2eea 0x216ac000 + 28394
    9   Medixcel Doctor                 0x000bec04 0x22000 + 642052
    10  Medixcel Doctor                 0x000be6fa 0x22000 + 640762
    11  libdispatch.dylib               0x21a85822 0x21a83000 + 10274
    12  libdispatch.dylib               0x21a92422 0x21a83000 + 62498
    13  libdispatch.dylib               0x21a91a60 0x21a83000 + 60000
    14  libdispatch.dylib               0x21a945e8 0x21a83000 + 71144
    15  libdispatch.dylib               0x21a93fcc 0x21a83000 + 69580
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c49b28 0x21c48000 + 6952
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c49718 0x21c48000 + 5912
    
    Thread 5 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21b8e8d0 0x21b8e000 + 2256
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21b8e6d4 0x21b8e000 + 1748
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x21ed9ac4 0x21e1e000 + 768708
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x21ed7e4c 0x21e1e000 + 761420
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x21e27228 0x21e1e000 + 37416
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x21e27014 0x21e1e000 + 36884
    6   Medixcel Doctor                 0x00099fa4 0x22000 + 491428
    7   Foundation                      0x227414a4 0x22665000 + 902308
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c4b85a 0x21c48000 + 14426
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c4b7ce 0x21c48000 + 14286
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c49724 0x21c48000 + 5924
    
    Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21ba2998 0x21b8e000 + 84376
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c4adec 0x21c48000 + 11756
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c4bc98 0x21c48000 + 15512
    3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x2164886c 0x21642000 + 26732
    4   JavaScriptCore                  0x251ce504 0x24fd7000 + 2061572
    5   JavaScriptCore                  0x251ce56e 0x24fd7000 + 2061678
    6   JavaScriptCore                  0x24fdf880 0x24fd7000 + 34944
    7   JavaScriptCore                  0x24fdf7de 0x24fd7000 + 34782
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c4b85a 0x21c48000 + 14426
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c4b7ce 0x21c48000 + 14286
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c49724 0x21c48000 + 5924
    
    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21ba2ffc 0x21b8e000 + 86012
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x21af6edc 0x21aec000 + 44764
    2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x216878b8 0x21642000 + 284856
    3   JavaScriptCore                  0x25389dfc 0x24fd7000 + 3878396
    4   JavaScriptCore                  0x25389bfc 0x24fd7000 + 3877884
    5   JavaScriptCore                  0x25389a9a 0x24fd7000 + 3877530
    6   JavaScriptCore                  0x2538b846 0x24fd7000 + 3885126
    7   JavaScriptCore                  0x2538b7e0 0x24fd7000 + 3885024
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c4b85a 0x21c48000 + 14426
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c4b7ce 0x21c48000 + 14286
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21c49724 0x21c48000 + 5924
    
    Thread 4 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
        r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
        r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x1f197000      r6: 0x38066304      r7: 0x1f195f78
        r8: 0x15651720    r9: 0x216a88fd     r10: 0x26ee6dde     r11: 0x15651744
        ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x1f195f6c      lr: 0x21c4c733      pc: 0x21ba2c5c
      cpsr: 0x00000010
    
    Binary Images:
    0x22000 - 0x211fff Medixcel Doctor armv7  <89d5d3f9cccd3ec7aed74d60a3dbc82a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE909A08-5A38-407B-A176-CBD73EE1D269/Medixcel Doctor.app/Medixcel Doctor
    0x3ca000 - 0x669fff libswiftCore.dylib armv7  <206df2bdf51b3c378f2f0b68a8bde656> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE909A08-5A38-407B-A176-CBD73EE1D269/Medixcel Doctor.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
    0x716000 - 0x71dfff libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib armv7  <8df9fecc2e923c8c8dbef4f74a937249> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE909A08-5A38-407B-A176-CBD73EE1D269/Medixcel Doctor.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
    0x72a000 - 0x739fff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib armv7  <223f351902af30368b43a7f60dec5e4c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE909A08-5A38-407B-A176-CBD73EE1D269/Medixcel Doctor.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
    0x74e000 - 0x755fff libswiftCoreImage.dylib armv7  <bca3d68f23af323f8f4f010053f031bb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE909A08-5A38-407B-A176-CBD73EE1D269/Medixcel Doctor.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
    0x762000 - 0x769fff libswiftDarwin.dylib armv7  <54c367456ce23af7bf2d5185767248fc> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE909A08-5A38-407B-A176-CBD73EE1D269/Medixcel Doctor.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
    0x2289d000 - 0x2297bfff libBLAS.dylib armv7  <3b647903060439dd81b6d852b828c808> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
    0x2297c000 - 0x22c45fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <76d8234bfe563de18b6a3f8c9727ef6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x22c46000 - 0x22e9efff vImage armv7  <b0481939c3043e19b603874339d52b73> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
    0x22e9f000 - 0x22eb0fff libvMisc.dylib armv7  <324e705b1dac3a809b793215d7575e88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
    0x22eb1000 - 0x22ec2fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib armv7  <dd988766e0b237f88de69b7df319f973> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x22ec3000 - 0x22ed7fff libSparseBLAS.dylib armv7  <828a031fc42635aa95ce451bb693f210> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x22ed8000 - 0x22f4dfff libvDSP.dylib armv7  <81660ad7288639ab82dfd36518c90cb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
    0x22f4e000 - 0x22f4efff vecLib armv7  <ce714ab612c534a1b1cbd498bd851006> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
    0x22f4f000 - 0x22f4ffff Accelerate armv7  <f2de5d457ef1361c84503912a662de48> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
    0x22f50000 - 0x2340dfff CoreGraphics armv7  <a1f5aea37c3f39e38ef81d167907d816> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
    0x2340e000 - 0x2341ffff GraphicsServices armv7  <f0bb6156889c3f43985f7a92f37bec98> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
    0x23420000 - 0x2345ffff AppSupport armv7  <8478366c21583944bd7275dd878eb20c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
    0x23460000 - 0x2351bfff MobileCoreServices armv7  <ec630bf558c637559ab2e5b535292919> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
    0x2351c000 - 0x23565fff BaseBoard armv7  <00f328aa722931a3b06c5a0843732f16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
    0x23566000 - 0x2356ffff AssertionServices armv7  <f5bdb0c4ff12316e9d9527c9e3010d74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
    0x23570000 - 0x23591fff BackBoardServices armv7  <7de2f79285fb3acdadffa9e18c96c673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
    0x23592000 - 0x23595fff MobileSystemServices armv7  <fe657fcb14f03b16ab36909ceb509565> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
    0x23596000 - 0x235c7fff FrontBoardServices armv7  <d976ddcbd723319ba884037470a616e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
    0x235c8000 - 0x235d1fff UserNotificationServices armv7  <d72021767b2a3095a2778db8be1055e4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserNotificationServices.framework/UserNotificationServices
    0x235d2000 - 0x235f8fff SpringBoardServices armv7  <6450d7693bdc3524bd750362e0bb1a08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
    0x235f9000 - 0x23607fff MobileKeyBag armv7  <8aaa865511f93d38a0a32422ca4f8bd9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
    0x23608000 - 0x2360dfff IOSurface armv7  <be0c566be52130009d2738cf9cf9b7d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
    0x2360e000 - 0x23619fff liblockdown.dylib armv7  <ee1f8bed602a362daea870f0473e1b7b> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
    0x2361a000 - 0x2362afff CrashReporterSupport armv7  <758bd1f065ee35aa929d889025e60dde> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
    0x2362b000 - 0x2362dfff IOSurfaceAccelerator armv7  <86b33e2d75df3e319084298687d043ab> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
    0x2362e000 - 0x23666fff AppleJPEG armv7  <b69488274caa3f80ab90017ff1ac2061> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
    0x23667000 - 0x23934fff ImageIO armv7  <173849bc22ed33c09393ef37ee0e9334> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
    0x23935000 - 0x23939fff TCC armv7  <ddb01002bf9137b8b231da07b42b2bbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
    0x2393a000 - 0x2393efff AggregateDictionary armv7  <4b79b155c9853dc2b81c41700f9743fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
    0x2393f000 - 0x2394afff PowerLog armv7  <fe75364bc9dd3948a1b09db11656513f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
    0x2394b000 - 0x239a2fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib armv7  <798c0fa46206306dbe1d28ede5acae3c> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
    0x239a3000 - 0x239b4fff CommonUtilities armv7  <d67f3f99c5083bdcbfc13a5d0110a8c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
    0x239b5000 - 0x239c7fff libcompression.dylib armv7  <f47b77be074a367082e6621df7874adf> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
    0x239c8000 - 0x23c00fff CoreData armv7  <8b0f949bbe703636b4c51a75c3920025> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
    0x23c01000 - 0x23c04fff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <2b45452691c232ecb0517a978667e2d7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x23c05000 - 0x23c09fff IOAccelerator armv7  <92d1d215dcab309b8add24ea9f6bc39b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
    0x23c0a000 - 0x23c0afff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <d4811e0f17db347f975f58e95b64a5d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x23c0b000 - 0x23c0dfff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <f1fd4e0ce0d33dc9bccd9a11a878e71d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
    0x23c0e000 - 0x23c4bfff libGLImage.dylib armv7  <95a4c5f889d83813b79250ea4ae63b81> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
    0x23c4c000 - 0x23c54fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <67e8a19ced973d56869643d0b33ef3c9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x23c55000 - 0x23c5bfff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <6ba3919c45d33789932bf63d5f149dc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
    0x23c5c000 - 0x23c5cfff libmetal_timestamp.dylib armv7  <c9ac3b99aba734679d9708fc2fe92f17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
    0x23c5d000 - 0x23c9cfff Metal armv7  <b4ca99dd28ef30e88d8888c703803f3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
    0x23c9d000 - 0x23ca5fff OpenGLES armv7  <7ce3ef00504a3af8ad9935aaa4ce9221> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
    0x23ca6000 - 0x23cbffff CoreVideo armv7  <5d715978310c3de5b1c16afe1250b2b0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
    0x23cc0000 - 0x23cc2fff OAuth armv7  <6aab365d245d3035b59da1ea5428f249> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
    0x23cc3000 - 0x23cf3fff Accounts armv7  <c83b4c146af232599e963363970bd248> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
    0x23cf4000 - 0x23de1fff libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <128e8025b7ac3ce39bac331c8ff7ba71> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x23de2000 - 0x23e93fff CoreAudio armv7  <2806e7f7057e3347b8ef67e2145d4cf4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
    0x23e94000 - 0x23e97fff UserFS armv7  <dacd455b700d3af484d818fb28be3699> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
    0x23e98000 - 0x23f5cfff CoreMedia armv7  <fa6be696b20330f29b72d4de3df053cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
.......
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Heimdal
    0x285b1000 - 0x285d1fff GSS armv7  <2059afd7dc273df2a6162a6cf671c576> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
    0x28621000 - 0x28629fff FMCoreLite armv7  <767fa8f1605f3aa6b836d280b601608f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FMCoreLite.framework/FMCoreLite
    0x2862a000 - 0x2862dfff MessageSupport armv7  <76826157d32531158f2d44dd37b655de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
    0x2862e000 - 0x2866efff MIME armv7  <df86b75f60ca30b794bdf5cb63ed2736> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
    0x2866f000 - 0x28674fff AOSNotification armv7  <f917d58b5754386098dbb21fbb9c4388> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
    0x28675000 - 0x286cffff AccountsDaemon armv7  <d183094acb9f337587a14299ae51625c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsDaemon.framework/AccountsDaemon
    0x286d0000 - 0x286edfff AppleIDSSOAuthentication armv7  <f353046f873931af92cb64cea789af81> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleIDSSOAuthentication.framework/AppleIDSSOAuthentication
    0x286ee000 - 0x286fcfff MailServices armv7  <a20960d220243ad39188eb8b918bdc48> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
    0x286fd000 - 0x28756fff AppleAccount armv7  <db7189d357ac3dcfaf461f968081bd33> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
    0x2875c000 - 0x2877efff ChunkingLibrary armv7  <b5e2778cf9ec3dc9971b26453a7b7b56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
    0x287a8000 - 0x287acfff AssetCacheServices armv7  <29dac9bc4b953d9d83cffc0628a2d8a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetCacheServices.framework/AssetCacheServices
    0x287ad000 - 0x28814fff MMCS armv7  <840e13b28cdd33df973e2bf07940e8fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
    0x28823000 - 0x2885ffff ContentIndex armv7  <f8c01838b8183d909fd06e39113ebf17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
    0x2896f000 - 0x2897efff UserManagement armv7  <f3f18a01d53b3bc994dcc7710528a67d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserManagement.framework/UserManagement
    0x2897f000 - 0x28a2bfff CorePDF armv7  <b73ba7073d1a31c9844440119dccf7c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
    0x28ca4000 - 0x28efdfff WebKit armv7  <3109afaf33b63912b58fe27cc359c189> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
    0x298e5000 - 0x298eafff CloudPhotoServices armv7  <1127ef23c31037e8a758219091beae6c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudPhotoServices.framework/CloudPhotoServices
    0x298eb000 - 0x299b2fff CloudPhotoLibrary armv7  <18f04c4d183c36ac85b0bb48fe4cea81> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudPhotoLibrary.framework/CloudPhotoLibrary
    0x299fc000 - 0x29a1efff AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <c15a6fc13aa5306286e062ecd544eb19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
    0x29aa9000 - 0x29ad2fff ACTFramework armv7  <49d9f1179471353d94fa7926dbb3ca70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ACTFramework.framework/ACTFramework
    0x29ad3000 - 0x29adefff DCIMServices armv7  <dfeee445a26a3e37a73c1d37a528661e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DCIMServices.framework/DCIMServices
    0x29adf000 - 0x29be1fff CoreMediaStream armv7  <c42de10993fd308593bdd1873c78d138> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
    0x29be2000 - 0x29bf7fff PhotosFormats armv7  <ffe34eaca2a03354a7a4e45b34e0a5bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotosFormats.framework/PhotosFormats
    0x29bf8000 - 0x29bfefff XPCKit armv7  <7c7c07ce8a6631bd904a5bd16d757dff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCKit.framework/XPCKit
    0x29e3c000 - 0x29f19fff CameraKit armv7  <ef510e3d3e593559ae62e3f797216a11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CameraKit.framework/CameraKit
    0x29f21000 - 0x29f39fff MediaStream armv7  <8e0e9b9f90e1381ab7937b2ffd68d586> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
    0x29f3a000 - 0x2a25afff PhotoLibraryServices armv7  <56c047446cf83606a90ec95cd28a7f93> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
    0x2ab76000 - 0x2ab88fff AssetsLibrary armv7  <81d6fa599c1d3dec84a93fb352224fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
    0x2ef82000 - 0x2efd6fff CoreBrightness armv7  <07520273b53737f6a1cae0c04c2a2662> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreBrightness.framework/CoreBrightness
    0x31c53000 - 0x31c56fff PushKit armv7  <d1d7fde2718f3996bc7050ce25e92fb2> /System/Library/Frameworks/PushKit.framework/PushKit
    
    Error Formulating Crash Report:
    Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

Comment: Must be because halloween is coming ... maybe it will go away later ...

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log to see where in your code it crashed.